# Coffescript not firing in Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments, railscasts

I'm trying to integrate stripe into an existing education based rails application. Before attempting to integrate stripe, I had a form which would create an order object and persist it to the db. I'm now attempting to include a payment on this form.

I've been following [Railscast 288](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?autoplay=true) to try and do this.

In the tutorial, the author triggers some actions in a coffeescript file.

The coffeescript was automatically generated when I generated the controller.

I can not get anything in my coffeescript to fire. I've tried this many times over the last couple of days, and I feel like I'm missing something small.

I'm looking for suggestions/places to look, or perhaps is there some compile step I'm missing that's not listed in the video?

I will be frantically refreshing my question once it's submitted, so if any code snippets are required, please let me know and I will edit.

Thanks!

> orders.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_dceOEJSyYW9EhsJOAPsmCosT')
  order.setupForm()

order =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        order.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, order.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
        alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

> application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

[Chrome developer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5i0I.png)

Comment: If you look at the page in the dev tools in your browser, is the compiled coffeescript code there?

Comment: Show the form html -- is it's id new_order?

Comment: So the `jQuery ->` callback is never executed? Is this Rails4 with Turbolinks?

Comment: @Tom Walpole Nope. Coffescript isn't there. Only bootstrap, stripe, and jquery. Form id is "new order".

Comment: @mu is too short I'm using Rails 4.2.4 on c9.io and I have no idea what turbolinks are :D

Comment: Ok - so if the coffeescript isn't even loading that would explain why it doesn't do anything - what is the contents of your application.js?

Comment: @Tom Walpole It's empty. Just has comments that were autogenrated.

Comment: Those "comments" mean something to the asset pipeline - add the contents to the question please

Comment: @TomWalpole Added   application.js

Comment: So the require tree portion should be loading the compiled orders.coffee - are you sure it's not being loaded in the browser?  Does the page work if you refresh it but not if you arrive on it from a different page?

Comment: what the `orders.js` in development mode keeps, when you visits the site?

Comment: I've addded a screenshot from chrome developer tools.